# Why doesn't TEXINPUTS work for fonts?

Tags: kpsewhich

I am using the environment variable `$TEXINPUTS` to set the search path for various files for a project.

It works for most files, but not for `Symbola.ttf` (or any `.ttf` file). `kpsewhich` does find the font files if they are in the current directory.

Am I missing something?

```
$ ls fonts
Symbola.ttf
$ ls tex
cvbooklet.cls
$ TEXINPUTS=fonts/:tex/: kpsewhich cvbooklet.cls
tex/cvbooklet.cls
$ TEXINPUTS=fonts/:tex/: kpsewhich Symbola.ttf
$ touch Symbola.ttf
$ TEXINPUTS=fonts/:tex/: kpsewhich Symbola.ttf
./Symbola.ttf
```

Comment: You could append the path to OSFONTDIR, one windows something like  `set OSFONTDIR=C:\Windows\Fonts\\;G:\Z-Test\font\\` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tfm font files are searched along `TFMFONTS` not `TEXINPUTS`, bibtex files on `BIBINPUTS` etc, see `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` or equivalent for all the paths used. `TTFONTS` seems to be what you need here.